# Can an authenticated encryption scheme detect if wrong key is used?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, key-check-value

Can an authenticated encryption scheme (like AES-GCM) detect if a wrong key is used for decryption? If not, what is the standard way to check whether the entered key is indeed correct. I presume KCVs can be used for this but does this somehow leak any information about the key?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. The answer is yes and no! AES-GCM and ChaCha20-Poly1305 is non-commiting! [Understanding the impact of partitioning oracle attacks on stream ciphers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88716/18298). A **committing encryption** scheme is a scheme that is computationally intractable to find a pair of keys and a ciphertext that decrypts under both keys. One need to use HMAC and KMAC.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was wondering what is the difference between a committing encryption scheme like [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2003/254.pdf) and a key committing scheme?

Comment: AFAIK, they are the same.

Answer (score 7):

This is an interesting question, and it depends on the situation where you might decrypt with the "wrong" key.

If two keys $k_1$ and $k_2$ are independently generated, and $c$ is an honestly generated ciphertext under $k_1$, then decrypting $c$ under $k_2$ will result in an error, except with negligible probability. If this weren't the case, it would lead to an attack against AEAD security (the attacker just submits a ciphertext under an independently chosen key). This analysis covers the case of "accidental" or "incidental" decryption under the wrong key.

However, this does not cover the case where $k_1, k_2, c$ are all generated adversarially. (Maybe an attacker shows you $c$ and $k_1$, and since $c$ decrypts successfully under $k_1$ you incorrectly conclude that someone with a different key could not have accepted $c$.) The usual definitions of AEAD don't prevent that. There are natural AEAD schemes (including AES-GCM) where it is possible to generate such $k_1, k_2, c$ such that $c$ decrypts without error under both $k_1$ and $k_2$. This property can indeed cause problems for some applications of AEAD, like [password-authenticated key agreement](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/163) and [abuse reporting in encrypted messaging](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/664).

If it is hard to come up with any $k_1, k_2, c$ where $c$ decrypts without error under both $k_1$ and $k_2$, then we say that the scheme is **key-committing**. Sometimes the key-committing property requires providing some additional value (apart from the usual ciphertext and key) to help bind the key to the ciphertext. Key-committing encryption is studied [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1456) and [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1153).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was wondering what is the difference between a **committing encryption** scheme like [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2003/254.pdf) and a **key committing** scheme?