# Key Committing AES-GCM

Tags: aes, tls, attack, aes-gcm, ghash

There is a [handful of attacks](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/sec21-len.pdf) against AEAD, and GCM in particular, which demonstrates that it is feasible for an attacker $\mathcal{A}$ to obtain a ciphertext $C$ which encrypts to multiple key/message pairs $(k_i, M_i)$.
This is commonly referred to AES-GCM not being *key-committing*.
Now, I'm a bit confused about the nature of the attacks that are possible with this, do I understand correctly that $\mathcal{A}$ needs to be able to 'modify' the ciphertext $C$ to be able to perform the outlined attacks?
Or is it also possible for $\mathcal{A}$, given a fixed $C$ encrypting $m_1$ under $k_1$, to obtain another decryption $m_2$ which yields $C$ under another key $k_2$?

Comment: [Can an authenticated encryption scheme detect if wrong key is used?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/96032/18298)

Comment: And the result of non-commitment; [Understanding the impact of partitioning oracle attacks on stream ciphers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88716/18298)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do I understand correctly that $\mathcal{A}$ needs to be able to 'modify' the ciphertext $C$ to be able to perform the outlined attacks?

No, these attacks assume that the attacker generates $C$; he takes a number of keys $k_1, k_2, ..., k_n$, and using those, generates a ciphertext $C$ that 'decrypts' successfully (that is, the integrity tag check succeeds) under all of them.

> Or is it also possible for $\mathcal{A}$, given a fixed $C$ encrypting $m_1$ under $k_1$, to obtain another decryption $m_2$ which yields $C$ under another key $k_2$?

We don't know how to do that; the attack we know about requires that the attacker has some flexibility in choosing $C$.  Now, he doesn't need to specify the entire value; he does need to specify at least 2 16-byte blocks to construct a $C$ that will decrypt under two different keys).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Very interesting, I read another paper which states that 
_Unlike CBC-HMAC, GCM is not committing [1](https://cs.nyu.edu/~dodis/ps/encryptment.pdf): for a given ciphertext and tag ($C$,$T$ ) encrypted with key
$k$, one can find $k'$ ≠ $k$ that decrypts $C$ to a different plaintext while
computing the same tag, as GCM MAC is not collision-resistant._
I suppose this claim is then incorrect, as the attack to this specific setting is unknown, no?

Comment: @SeminalWorker: yes, I believe that paper misstates things; you need some flexibility in choosing the ciphertext and/or tag (unless they are assuming flexibility in choosing the AAD, which for this attack can be treated as ciphertext).

Comment: @SeminalWorker: here's the issue: the tag computation can be summarized as $F(C, H) + G(K, IV) = tag$; they note that $F$ doesn't have a lot of cryptographical strength; for example, given $C$ and $F(C, H)$, we can efficiently find all the $H$ values that would generate that target value (and there is often more than 1).  On the other hand, $H$ (and $G(K, IV)$) are a complex function of the key; given a value of $H$ that we want, we don't know how to generate a key that would generate that $H$.