# Using AES-256-GCM, is your security only 128 bits when solely relying on the MAC?

Tags: aes, mac, aes-gcm

Since the maximum authentication tag (MAC) size of AES-256-GCM is 16 bytes,

And given that in one implementation, that breaking the MAC would break the security (ex. when a boolean 'decrypted' is used to either deny or allow access),

Would using an additional MAC within the cipherText be a good idea or is this over-engineering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference of nature between the $k$-bit bit security a $k$-bit key gives, and the $t$-bit security a $t$-bit authentication tag gives.

In the case of a key, adversaries can try keys by brute force, and after trying $2^n$ keys the security is reduced from $k$ to $k-n$-bit, that is there is probability $1/2^{\approx\max(k-n,0)}$ that the key search was successful. $n$ is limited only by the computing power of the adversary. $n=96$ may be realistic (see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/13305/555)) if the stakes are high.

In the case of a tag, adversaries can try tags, and after try $2^n$ they have probability $1/2^{\approx\max(t-n,0)}$ the right tag was reached. But they can only verify it by interacting with an entity (device, service). This severely limits $n$. e.g. with a 1 Gbit/s link and 128 bits per try, we are at $n<48$ after a year.

There are a few other differences:

|  | key | tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| limit factor for brute force attack | computing power | verification oracle speed |
| realistic $n$ for $2^n$ values tested | 72-96 | 16-48 |
| hypothetical [CRQC](https://crqc.grieu.fr) could further help | yes | no |
| attack possible in the future from captured transcripts | yes | no |
| attack recovers key (total break) | yes | no |

For these reasons, *save for an attack better than brute force* (e.g.     platform compromise, side channel, IV reuse, cryptanalysis, [Partitioning Oracle Attack](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1491) if applicable [see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88716/555)]…), a 128-bit tag seems fine in every application, when a 128-bit symmetric key arguably is closer to problematic for high-stakes security when long-term confidentiality matters.

> Would using an additional MAC within the cipherText be a good idea or is this over-engineering?

If the only concern is the size of the tag, that would be over engineering. If on the other hand it's used a different key for the MAC, or/and it it there to mitigate some real threat beyond guess of the tag, it may add a barrier to exploitation.

Comment: Excellent summary. However, I would note that adding an additional MAC is a [recommended](https://doc.libsodium.org/secret-key_cryptography/aead#robustness) step to prevent partitioning oracle attacks/commitment issues. That's perhaps the best [argument](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/100852/102678) for Encrypt-then-MAC.